# returning a new array of rankings based on initial array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm new to javascript and am trying to create a function that accepts an array of any length, and creates a new array with the rankings from that array (ie [10, 5, 20] would output [2, 3, 1]. This is my code so far ( i originally tried with a larger series of for loops finding the max each time but ran into issues getting them to repeat the same number of times as there are numbers in the array, so I switched to a sort method. Let me know if anyone can help point me in the right direction, thank you!!

```
function rankings(array){
  let finalArray = [];
 for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {//set up final array
  finalArray[i] = array[i];
   }
  for(let list of array){
    array.sort((a,b)=>b-a)//array sorted in order
    }
    for (i = array.length-1; i>=0; i--){

    }
  return finalArray;
}
```

Comment: Would help if you explained why `[10, 5, 20]` should return `[2, 3, 1]`. The relationship is not clear and neither is your term "rankings". Also provide some sample data and expected results

Comment: The way I understand it, `10, 5, 20` should return `2, 1, 3` and not `2, 3, 1`. Otherwise I don't see what you mean by 'ranking'.

Comment: what about same values? do they get the same rank?

Comment: hi - sorry about the confusion! the highest number in the array will be '1' and it will count up from there(2nd highest is two, lowest is length of array). here are some examples of data and expected results: rankings([6, 8, 1, 12, 4, 3, 9]); // [4, 3, 7, 1, 5, 6, 2]
rankings([100]); // [1]
rankings([4, 2, 3, 1]); // [1, 3, 2, 4]

Answer (score 0):

Sort a clone (via spread) of the array, according to your ranking logic (descending in this case). Use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create tuples of [value, index + 1], and generate a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) from the tuples.

Use `Array.map()` on the original array, and return the respective ranks from the Map:

```js
function rankings(array) {
  const ranks = new Map([...array].sort((a, b) => b - a)
    .map((v, i) => [v, i + 1]))

  return array.map(v => ranks.get(v));
}

const result = rankings([10, 5, 20]);

console.log(result);
```

To ignore repeat values, create a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) from the original array before spreading it:

```js
function rankings(array) {
  const ranks = new Map([...new Set(array)].sort((a, b) => b - a)
    .map((v, i) => [v, i + 1]))

  return array.map(v => ranks.get(v));
}

const result = rankings([10, 5, 20, 5]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like to get same ranks fro same values, cou could take the stored value for mapping.

```js
const
    rankings = array => array.map(
        Map.prototype.get,
        [...array]
            .sort((a, b) => b - a)
            .reduce((i => (m, v) => m.set(v, m.get(v) || i++))(1), new Map)
    );

const result = rankings([10, 5, 20, 5]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give this a try:

```js
var data = [10, 5, 20, 5, 4, 25];
var sorted = [...new Set([...data].sort((a,b)=>b-a))] // sorting and filtering the data
var result = data.map(elem=> getIndex = sorted.findIndex(v=>v==elem)+1);
console.log(result);
```